# java.lang.AssertionError:Status Expected:<200>but was:<400>

Tags: junit, spring-test, assertion

```
@Test
public void appFormSubmissionTest() throws Exception {
AppFormSubmissionBOResponse resonse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
       AppFormSubmissionBOResponse.class.getResourceAsStream("/appFormSubmission_BO_Resp.json"),
       new TypeReference<AppFormSubmissionBOResponse>() {});

Mockito.when(apiCallImpl.invokeSubmitApplicationForm(any(String.class),any(HttpEntity.class))).thenReturn(resonse);

this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/appformsubmission")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .content(new ObjectMapper().readValue(ChanelRequest.class.getResourceAsStream("/appFormSubmissionChanelRequest.json"),
                                                  new TypeReference<ChanelRequest<AppFormDetails>>() {}).toString())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))               
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.dataEntity.pdfUrl", is("")));
}
```

For this code, I am getting below error.
java.lang.AssertionError:Status Expected:<200>but was:<400>

Here is the controller class

```
@PostMapping(path = "/appformsubmission")
public ChanelResponse<AppFormSubmissionResponse> saveAppForm(
        @RequestBody ChanelRequest<AppFormDetails> requestObject) throws JsonProcessingException {

    logger.info("MwController -saveAppForm ");
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Entering MwController() method");
        logger.debug("requestObject : {}", Utility.toJsonString(requestObject));
    }
    return appFormService.submitApplicationForm(requestObject);
}
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: In test you are mocks `Mockito.when(apiCallImpl.invokeSubmitApplicationForm(` but in controller you call `return appFormService.submitApplicationForm(`,  I guess it is reason of error, because the methods are different.

Comment: I tried this not working.

Comment: Any other solution for this?

Comment: In case if you change something, please provide actual example of source code, because you have also mistake in quantity of mocked methods parameters in addition to method name (i mentioned previously) without actually source code I can not help you.

Comment: Borino source code you want for service?

Comment: because you are mocked service their source code is does not matter, i need actual version of source code your test method.

Comment: Here is my test case

Comment: did you change code according my previous comments ?? If not please  change and renew your example.

Comment: Borino I am notable to add source code in comments.

Comment: Can I have your email ID so that I can send you the source code?

Comment: you can edit your question, or add as an answer